# Keep the Sabath

Tags: biblical-basis, jehovahs-witnesses, sabbath

Can you tell me why is there 10 commanmends for Christian's to follow but I was told by a JW neighbour when I asked about the sabbath being holy and meant that we stop doing all the other things we do like shopping on the remainder 6 days and that keeping the Sabeth day holy meant besides worshiping that we need not shop nor allow others living with us do so, that I was told  doesn't apply. 
Why is the sabbath only half adhered to?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. This is a site that discusses the beliefs of many different Christian denominations and traditions.  You need to specify the Christian tradition or denomination from which you seek answers and avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based. If you want an answer from Jehovah's Witnesses, please add their tag. Good questions show research and provide evidence of any claims made.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/christian-sabbath/. Your question is unclear but if you are asking why JWs don’t keep the sabbath this link will help

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about Jehovah's Witnesses specifically, you could read one of their publications on the subject, such as [Must Christians Keep the Sabbath?](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/christian-sabbath/), which says:

> Christians are not required to observe a weekly sabbath. Christians
>   are under “the law of the Christ,” which does not include keeping the
>   Sabbath.

They believe that any obligation to observe the Sabbath (or any specific day of the week) was removed at the time of Jesus's death, though they do allow individual choice on the matter.

The same article lists several of their ideas on the subject:

> - Misconception: God instituted the Sabbath when he rested on the seventh day
> - Misconception: The Israelites were under the Sabbath law before they received the Law of Moses.
> - Misconception: The Sabbath is a perpetual covenant and is therefore still required.
> - Misconception: Christians must keep the Sabbath, since Jesus kept it.
> - Misconception: The apostle Paul observed the Sabbath as a Christian.
> - Misconception: The Christian Sabbath is on Sunday.
> - Misconception: It is wrong to set aside one day every week for rest and worship.

---

Most other denominations obviously don't agree with their reasoning.  They see no evidence in the Bible that removes the commandment to honour the Sabbath.

For instance, the Roman Church and most of its Protestant daughter churches believe that the Sabbath *should* be honoured, but that the Pope was able to *move* the holy day to Sunday.

> James Cardinal Gibbons, **The Faith of our Fathers**, 88th ed., pp. 89.
>
> "But you may read the Bible from Genesis to Revelation, and you will
>   not find a single line authorizing the sanctification of Sunday. The
>   Scriptures enforce the religious observance of Saturday, a day which
>   we never sanctify."

And:

> Stephen Keenan, **A Doctrinal Catechism** 3rd ed., p. 174.
>
> "Question:  Have you any other way of proving that the Church has
>   power to institute festivals of precept?
>
> "Answer:  Had she not such power, she could not have done that in
>   which all modern religionists agree with her -- she could not have
>   substituted the observance of Sunday, the first day of the week, for
>   the observance of Saturday, the seventh day, a change for which there
>   is no Scriptural authority."

And:

> Peter R. Kraemer, **Catholic Church Extension Society** (1975), Chicago,
>   Illinois.
>
> ...
>   "That Protestants, who accept the Bible as the only rule of faith and religion, should by all means go back to the observance of
>   the Sabbath. The fact that they do not, but on the contrary observe
>   the Sunday, stultifies them in the eyes of every thinking man.
>   ... It is always somewhat laughable, to see the Protestant churches, in pulpit and legislation, demand the observance of Sunday, of which
>   there is nothing in their Bible."

Quotations taken from [Roman Catholic statements about the Sabbath](https://www.biblesabbath.org/confessions.html)

---

The Seventh Day Adventist Church, and many other denominations, believe that the Bible is the only authority, and so don't accept the Pope's authority and continue to honour God's original Sabbath day.  E.g.: [Sunset to Sunset -- God's Sabbath Rest](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/sunset-to-sunset-gods-sabbath-rest).

Comment: What does honoring the sabbath mean in the 21st century church?

Comment: Protestants don't believe the pope had anything to do with moving the Sabbath to Sunday. For that matter I don't think that's Catholic teaching either.

Comment: @Caleb, did you read the quotations from the Catholic authors and catechism?  There is nothing in the Bible to support moving the Sabbath, and the Catholic Church flaunts this fact at the Protestants.

Answer (score 0):

The 10 commandments were given only to the Jews via Moses.  Christians have the 2 "greatest" (most important) commandments (Matthew 22:36-40) given to us by someone far more 
 than Moses; Jesus; thus we need no more!

Besides, who can any have a whole year of work in to-days world:-

> NIV Lev 25:3-5  "For six years sow your fields, and for six years prune your vineyards and gather their crops. 4 **But in the seventh year the land is to have a year of sabbath rest, a sabbath to the LORD**. Do not sow your fields or prune your vineyards. 5 Do not reap what grows of itself or harvest the grapes of your untended vines. The land is to have a year of rest."